# Date Format in standard JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time

I have a date in "Mar 15, 2017 5:06:16 PM" format and i have to convert it into browser's timezone which i am doing using "Date" in javascript but the final time i am getting is in  "3/15/2017, 5:06:16 PM" format i have to change it to "Mar 15, 2017 5:06:16 PM"

How this can be achieved using JavaScript?

I have tried JavaScript inbuilt functions like

(1) toISOString

(2) toLocalString

(3) toUTCString

but no luck, i feel like there is no standard js method. can anyone provide me that piece of code which can change it into the desired format ?

Comment: you should really consider using momentjs library, its powerful and all you want can be achieved with moment's functions...

Comment: Comment in case this wouldn't work, but moment.js is a very helpful library for all things Date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: i would suggest using moment.js. Usually when you plan on working a lot with date objects, the library offers a great variety of utilities such as custom formats, date parsing, relative time, etc

Comment: Actually this is the only use case i have with date so i dont want to use moment.js but i believe there must be something using which i can format my date.

Comment: Take in spelling JavaScript to avoid search collision with Java.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use different methods, you can simply use string manipulation, if you want a custom date string display and don't want to load any additional libraries such as momentjs:

```
var months = [ 'Jan', ... ];
var parts = Date.toString() // 3/15/2017, 5:06:16 PM
            .split('/');    // [ "3", "15", "2017, 5:06:16 PM" ]

console.log( months[ parts[ 0 ] ] + " " + parts[ 1 ] + ", " + parts[ 2 ] );
```

This is definitely not the only solution, but whenever you want to change the display format of anything, you can always remind yourself that you can use string manipulation. A more semantically correct way to do it would be not to do any string manipulation, but by placing `Date.getMonth` in the wanted part of a string, for example.

If you're using ES6, you can make it very pretty:

```
console.log( `${monthString} ${dayNum}, ${yearNum} ${hourNum % 12}:${leftPad(minuteNum,2)}:${leftPad(secondNum,2)} ${hourNum < 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'} ` );
```

Comment: this will definitely decrease the code standard, thats why i decided not to use this

Comment: it's up to you to write the full semantically correct code and make it pretty. But this is the most sensible way, so long as you don't want to use a library

Comment: @whishky If you don't want to use a library, then you'll have to do something similar to this answer. There is no standard function that would format the date the way you want it.

Comment: @JJJ I guess saying it this way that "there is no other way" seems a bit rude, we can always use that "as far as i know". anyway thanks for the help